# How to move 2 images at the same time in C# for Windows Phone App?

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, drag, gesture

I have 2 images barTop and barBottom. If I drag the barTop, I want barBottom to be dragged along too. The codes that I have is below. May I know how can I do it?

```
private void GestureListener_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        barTopTT.X += e.HorizontalChange;
        barTopTT.Y += e.VerticalChange;
        barBottomTT.X += e.HorizontalChange;
        barBottomTT.Y += e.VerticalChange;
    }
```

Comment: I guess you're asking because this code doesn't work?

Comment: @John It does not work. Currently, I could only move 1 image at a time.

Comment: If you remove all mentions of `barTopTT` in your method and try to move only `barBottomTT`, does it work?

Comment: @KooKiz After removing it, it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    <Image Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Name="img1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/1.png">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="img1gesture"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta_1"/>
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    </Image>
    <Image Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Name="img2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/1.png">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="img2gesture"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta_1"/>
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    </Image>
```

In C#,

```
    private void GestureListener_DragDelta_1(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        img1gesture.TranslateX += e.HorizontalChange;
        img2gesture.TranslateX += e.HorizontalChange;
        img1gesture.TranslateY += e.VerticalChange;
        img2gesture.TranslateY += e.VerticalChange;
    }
```

Comment: @AmitKunmar Hi, i'm sorry as this is not what I am looking for. I want both the bars(image) to move even if I just move 1 of the bar.

Comment: Here in this code if you move a single image then both images will move, did you try this or not?

Comment: Yes, I did tried it. However, both images are not moving together.

Comment: It is working now! I forgot to remove the previously code for MouseDragBehaviorElement. Thank you very much!